# How to make SQL query faster with paging?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an ecommerce website with a shop page, each shop page contain 6 products and user can filter according to size and category, then user must press next to get next 6 products. google pagespeed index says that TTFB is about 0.7 seconds which is mostly taken by SQL query yet i have only 23 product which i expect to increase dramatically when i add more products.
mysql query looks like this in php file.

```
$q = "
    SELECT  products.name, products.colors, products.sizes,
            products.selling_price,
            products.id, products.size_chart, products.about
        FROM  products 
";
$q .= $filter_options;
```

`$filter_options` is returned from another function which makes the entire query to be like this on first page (page 1) when i echo `$q` without applying size and category filters only sorting.

```
    SELECT  products.name, products.colors, products.sizes,
            products.selling_price,
            products.id, products.size_chart, products.about
        FROM  products
        INNER JOIN  category  ON category.id = products.category_id
        WHERE  1 = 1
        ORDER BY  products.selling_price Desc
        LIMIT  0,6
```

and here is the query with category and size filters are applied

```
    SELECT  products.name, products.colors, products.sizes,
            products.selling_price,
            products.id, products.size_chart, products.about
        FROM  products
        INNER JOIN  category  ON category.id = products.category_id
        WHERE  1 = 1
          AND  FIND_IN_SET('s', products.sizes)>0
          AND  category.name = 'Dresses'
        ORDER BY  products.selling_price Desc
        LIMIT  0,6
```

My limitation are:

i cant limit number of results by `WHERE products.id < $some_page_index` since products ID are not continous since i add and remove products directly which makes id like `1 2 4 10` so it will result in less than 6 products on some pages.

Comment: What's the question? The second page will be `LIMIT 6, 6`, and so on.

Comment: Make sure you have an index on `selling_price` to make the ordering efficient.

Comment: @Barmar Yes the website works perfectly but it's very slow considering i have only 23 products in the database so how can i make this query faster ?

Comment: @Barmar i can have an index on selling_price but I guess the problem is mostly in the limit statement since limit will just return all the records and then it will just return a subset of it, yet I couldn't find another way to implement my paging mechanism.

Comment: There isn't really any way to optimize LIMIT. The database has to generate all the results up to the limit.

Comment: @Barmar i edited my question with how the query looks like when size and category filters are applied

Comment: So the best you can do is optimize the ordering.

Comment: Also, make sure `products.category_id` is declared to be a foreign key. That will index it so the join is efficient.

Comment: @Barmar category_id is indeed a foreign key. but if i cant make things more optimized this will mean when i add 100 product the time will be much slower right (like over 1 second)? or indexing the ```selling_price``` will result in things being much faster ?

Comment: If you're getting poor performance with only 23 rows in the table, there's something wrong with your server, maybe it doesn't have enough memory. You shouldn't start to notice performance issues until you have many thousands of rows.

Comment: You should probably hire an experienced system administrator, we're not going to be able to troubleshoot this here.

Comment: @Barmar thanks alot I also thought something must be wrong but i'm not a professional database engineer so i thought that something must be wrong in my query ?

Comment: No, this query is extremely simple, there's nothing you can do to improve it.

Comment: `i cant limit number of results by` I think there’s a misunderstanding there btw. You don’t need continuous id sequences to do `order by unique_field where unique_field > :last limit 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing "pagination", don't use `OFFSET`, instead "remember where you left off":  [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Do you at least have these indexes?

```
category:  INDEX(name)
products:  INDEX(category_id, selling_price)
```

I recommend looking over the queries that are used, then building composite indexes starting with the column(s) tested with `=`.

There are practical limits on how many columns in an index and how many different indexes to have.  If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, do not also have `INDEX(a)`.  More: [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

MySQL cannot provide a perfect indexing mechanism for an app like yours.

**More**

I should point out that *seemingly minor* changes to the query and table schema *may* have drastic impact on the query, especially wrt paginating.

If there are only 6-7 "categories", indexing that table is unlikely to have a noticeable effect.  (Still, I recommend adding UNIQUE(name).)

The big problem in paginating of the given query is that all the possible rows are located, then sorted, then the desired 6 are delivered to the user.  So, there is not a lot of difference for page 1 versus page 100.

To make page 1 run faster than that, there needs to be an `INDEX` that handles *all* of the `WHERE` plus handles the `ORDER BY`.  With such, the 6 rows can [probably] be found with without looking at the entire table an sorting it.

Things that prevent that desirable optimization:

- Non-[*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expressions in `WHERE` (such as `FIND_IN_SET(...)`)
- `JOINs`.  (Actually, your `JOIN` may be an exception -- I think it will *start* by scanning that tiny table for all ids of `Dresses`, then use them (without realizing that there is only one) for starting a partial scan of `products`.
- Something that *might* help is getting rid of `categories` and simply having `category_name` in `products` *instead of*`category_id`.
- Note that a composite index such as `(category, selling_price)` can be efficiently used if it knows that there is only one category.  That way it can be more efficient by then moving on to the range requested for `sellint_price`.

(At least you are not using the EAV (open-ended key-value) schema design; it is much worse at optimizing.)

Comment: if the category table have only 7 or 6 rows would there be any benefit from indexing it ?

Comment: @KMG - I rambled on.  Sorry for being long-winded.

Comment: @KMG - It won't hurt to add such an index.  It may help.

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT offset, count;` is only work when the records is small. If large table, you can use condition like:

ID is a primary key or unique key(not null)

```
select * from table where ID>last_query_id limit offset, count order by ID;
```

As the query optimizer can use ID for range scan to improve query performance.